# Remove bottom branding from tiny mce in django templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, tinymce, django-tinymce

I am using tiny mce HtmlField() in my django models. Every thing works file but the bottom branding in the field annoys me. Is there any way to remove branding in django template. [image: I have to get rid of this branding is there any way]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This supposed to work.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce-div',

    // Disable branding message, remove "Powered by TinyMCE"
    branding: false
});
```

note: If you are developing a product using there open source license you should consider keeping the text. That's a courtesy we all should follow.

Comment: Ok, but where am I supposed to add this piece of code. Adding It inside the script tag in  my template doesn't work

Comment: @SANJEEVKM inside your script field where you are initializing tinymce

Comment: Adding It inside the script tag in my template doesn't work

Comment: please update your question with your script where you initialized the tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

To disable it go in `settings.py` and add these line -

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'branding': False,
    'height': 460,
    'width': 900,
}
```

You can adjust height and width as per your requirement